# Identification of tangent spaces by parallel transport along geodesics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles

Given a geodesically complete manifold M, can we define a global identification of tangent spaces by starting from a base point, and parallel transporting along smooth geodesics?  For this to be consistent, we need the parallel transport along every geodesic loop to leave the tangent space invariant.  Is there a simple condition on M that tells me whether this is possible?

(I am not a mathematician so I apologize if what I asked was not very precise.)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but... can you explain how 'curvature' isn't an immediate impediment? (it's also possible/likely I'm just not understanding your question!)

Comment: This does not work on the round 2-sphere, because it fails on the antipodal point. In fact no identification is possible for the tangent spaces of a 2-sphere.

Comment: @DCM Curvature is definitely a problem if we do not consider geodesics, or if we consider a piecewise geodesic curve (like a triangle).  I was wondering whether what I said could make sense if we only transport along smooth geodesics.

Comment: @BrunoMartelli Thank you for your comment. Indeed 2-sphere seems bad...let me modify my question.

Comment: @DCM I think I agree with you...

Comment: Isn't this related to the notion of holonomy? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy

Comment: What do you mean by "define a global identification"? Do you mean "trivialize the tangent bundle"? If so, in which category? Topological or smooth?

Comment: For your idea to work you need to guarantee that any two smooth geodesic segments which begin at p and end at q induce the same holonomy map, lest your parallel transport from p to q be ill-defined. This is certainly false on the 2-sphere if you take q = -p. I would be unsurprised were someone to tell me this claim is true iff M is flat, but I don't see a proof. (If one replaces "geodesic segment" by "piecewise geodesic segment" this implies M is flat.)

Comment: It seems clear to me that this is possible in non-flat cases-- after all, on any complete manifold where the exponential map at a point is bijective, such as hyperbolic space, we can unambiguously identify the tangent spaces in this way. Perhaps some additional condition will make flatness necessary?

Comment: @Bma Thank you for your comment. My main interest is the non-compact symmetric space O(m,n)/(O(m)xO(n)). I wonder if in this case the exponential map at a point is bijective, just like in hyperbolic space. More generally, I am curious if there is a simple characterization for when the exponential map is bijective.

Comment: @mme Yes thank you. I realized this for the 2-sphere after Bruno's comment. The flatness condition might be true if we restrict to compact manifolds, but as Bma pointed out it also works on hyperbolic space. For non-compact manifolds, I wonder if being contractible is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Now that I think of it, perhaps what I said was indeed the same as trivializing the tangent bundle. I want to consider smooth manifolds.

Comment: Then you want a manifold whose exponential map $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism (for some $p\in M$), such a point $p$ is known as a"pole". The most common sufficient condition for this is to have a Hadamard manifold $M$ (complete, simply connected, of nonpositive curvature). Does it help?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes very helpful, thank you! Is O(m,n)/(O(m)xO(n)) Hadamard?

Comment: Yes, it is, it's one of the classical symmetric spaces of noncompact type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, given the comments, what you are really asking for, is for a class of connected Riemannian manifolds for which the following construction (or the map $\Phi$) is a (smooth) trivialization of the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold $M$:

Fix a $p\in M$. For each $q\in M$ let $\gamma_{qp}$ denote a unit speed geodesic connecting $q$ to $p$. Let $\Pi_{qp}: T_qM\to T_pM$ denote the parallel transport along $\gamma_{qp}$. Then take the map
$$
\Phi: TM\to M\times T_pM, \quad \Phi(v)=(q, \Pi_{qp}(v)), \quad v\in T_qM.
$$

Then a **sufficient** (likely, also necessary, at the very least, you will need injectivity of the exponential map) condition for this to work is when $M$ has a **pole** at $p$, i.e. $\exp_p: T_pM\to M$ is a diffeomorphism. (This ensures that $\gamma_{qp}$ exists, is unique and depends smoothly on $q$.) For instance, by the [Cartan-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), it suffices to assume that $M$ is complete, simply connected and has sectional curvature $\le 0$. An example which has positive curvature is a paraboloid of revolution in ${\mathbb R}^3$ (the point $p$ will be the tip of the paraboloid).